# Ruby finding element with max value in multidimensional array using max_by

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement `max_by` to find element with highest value  in multidimensional array.
code as follows

```
ar = [[123,345,43,35,43,1],[456,123,43,35,43,1],[675,123,43,35,43,1],[123,123,43,35,43,321]]
x = ar.max_by { |a,b| a <=> b }
p "result #{x.inspect}"
```

And the output is `" result [456, 123, 43, 35, 43, 1]"`
Can you please explain to me what's wrong with my code ?

**Update 1**
using max_by

```
ar  = [ {a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]
x = ar.max_by { |e| e[:a] }
p "result #{x.inspect}"
```

I've left this update as a reminder for myself of whoever may bump into similar problem

Comment: Unless you show what you wanted or how it is different from what you got, we cannot tell what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I wanted to find element of the array with greater value. Thanks to @arup that was solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do :

```
ar = [[123,345,43,35,43,1],[456,123,43,35,43,1],[675,123,43,35,43,1],[123,123,43,35,43,321]]
x = ar.max { |a,b| a.max <=> b.max }
```

With `#max_by`, you are passing each element *array*, and then `|a, b|`, actually doing parallel assignment on `a` and `b`. This is not what you want I trust. What I have given above is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for  correction of my mistake. `max_by` should be used only with hashed?

Answer (score 3):

`max_by` handles the comparison for you, just return the maximum value for *one* element:

```
ar.max_by { |a| a.max }
#=> [675, 123, 43, 35, 43, 1]
```

Or even shorter:

```
ar.max_by(&:max)
#=> [675, 123, 43, 35, 43, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm not mistaken then you'll need to find the greatest values of each subarray and the results should be something like:

```
[345, 456, 675, 321]
```

If that what are you looking for:

```
x = ar.map{|x| x.max}
```